# How to use Python or pyodbc module with proxy settings?

Tags: python, proxy, centos, redhat, pyodbc

I am working on a project that is deployed on an On-Premise VM. The on-prem VM is using a proxy setting to connect to the Internet. Now I have a Python script that connects to Azure SQL Server using the pyodbc module. I am able to ping and telnet various sources to check my internet connectivity but I'm unable to go to the Azure SQL Server.

I have tried various approaches like enabling and disabling proxy settings over both HTTP and HTTPS, enabling 1433 port on the firewall and working with my office network team to resolve this.

How can I resolve this issue? Do we have any way to use proxy with either Python or pyodbc?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: The Client haven't given access via opening the port on the machine. After tracing the routes, I asked them to do so and it worked. I'm sorry to disappoint you here but usually this is the case when we are unable to connect, somewhere in the system, we leave some configurations that should be done.